# PDF with 200 DPI JPEGs look blurry in viewer

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader

I often scan images, and I usually do that as 200 DPI JPEG files. If I look at them in Gwenview (Linux image viewer) the text looks readable, and on 100% it looks perfectly sharp.

When I convert them into a PDF, using convert from the Imagick package and open that in Okular or Evince (Linux document viewer) the text looks blurry.

I wrote a little script that creates a HTML page with all the images and opens it in the browser. Firefox scales the images a little sharper than the PDF viewers.

**Firefox JPEGs**:

[image: Firefox JPEG]

---

**Evince PDF**

[image: Evince PDF]

---

Is there any way to get the PDF to scale the images sharply?

Comment: That is a lot of smoothing going on, vrses other zoom methods. I would still wonder if you increased the contrast on the image , did a sharpen of the image, and reduced the noise some , that the displaying smoothing might not look "as bad". you even have low level bleedthrough from the other side of the page?  Use the Levels, and overdo the processing of the original and see if that helps? http://superuser.com/questions/401294/print-page-without-noise-page-color/401341#401341 Improving the simplicity of the image, will help the compression some.